# New message causes a fatal error

Tags: forms, privatemsg

I am facing following error in logs and white screen on sending new message through Private Message Module (Open Social Distribution 11.9.4).

> Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorageException: Parameter "private_message_thread" for route "entity.private_message_thread.canonical" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL. in Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage->save() (line 815 of ../html/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Entity/Sql/SqlContentEntityStorage.php).

I have these Composer dependencies installed.

- `"drupal/menu_items_visibility": "^1.1"`
- `"drupal/disable_field": "^3.0"`
- `"drupal/colorbox": "^2.0"`
- `"drupal/slick": "^2.7"`
- `"drupal/geolocation": "^3.12"`
- `"drupal/honeypot": "^2.1"`
- `"drupal/captcha": "^1.9"`
- `"drupal/role_watchdog": "^2.0"`